# anime fonts don't display correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, fonts

I enjoy watching a lot of English fansubbed anime.

and unlike everyday srt subtitles, fansubbed anime uses variety of 10 to 20 fonts just for one 20 minute episode.

on windows, I don't have this problem and I'm sure that this is not an app or even os problem. I've had this problem with mpv and vlc over ubuntu distros and now with fedora 35 workstation.

the fonts aren't rendered correctly. they don't use the appropriate font their size and measure is wrong and they overlap each other.

what bugs me is as I said this is a universal problem in a unix-like environment.

and I admit I don't know where to look for a solution.
we know it's not the apps, we know it's not the os (maybe). It could be a codec issue. how do I install external codecs and use them to play my anime instead??

do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it looks to me that you need to install all the missing fonts. A text sample or link to the subtitle file would help.

Comment: but all the fonts are already embedded to the file. and we're talking about a lot fonts per every anime

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what subtitle file format do you use and provide a screenshot of "fonts aren't rendered correctly".